# What can be done with duplication of answer

Tags: discussion, answers

Sometimes I found out on single question One answered and after some time another answer which is very similar to 1st (may with negligible too-minor edit), say duplication of 1st answer!

Which seems not Right Way.

What actions can be done against duplication? Or what to do with such answer-post?

Comment: You mean the same answer twice in the same question, or something else?

Comment: @Braiam yes by different user.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Let's go over three of the main scenarios involving duplicate answers (these are the ones I see the most).

1. User A posts an answer "You need to foo the bar". User B comes along and posts an answer "You need to foo the bar" and then goes on to explain *why* he needs to foo the bar, and *how* to foo the bar. I upvote user B's answer and move on (sometimes I downvote user A's answer as well).
2. User Z asks a question "How do I get baz to run properly?". User A posts an answer "You need to foo the bar" 1 minute after the question is asked. User B posts an answer "You need to foo the bar" 1 minute and 15 seconds after the question is asked. I normally ignore this, as long as it isn't actively causing problems (hopefully one user will expand on their answer).
3. User A posts an answer "You need to foo the bar". 2 months later, User B posts an answer "You need to foo the bar." I delete these, they don't serve any useful purpose. Go ahead and flag them.

Our goal on Ask Ubuntu is to generate good content that will help someone else in the future. A general rule of thumb is: if an answer adds something useful to the post it should probably stay.

Comment: To 1. Why downvoting A's answer? Often even an answer this short helps to solve the problem - and sometimes fast help is of more need than exhaustive explanations

Comment: @Ristridin You are absolutely right, which is why I said "sometimes" in my answer ;)

Comment: reply to step3: And flag both answers(?) as ***"Not an answer"*** flag(?) or ***"VLQ"*** ?

Comment: @KasiyA Which one do you think? If you read the description of the flags, VLQ doesn't really fit. Use NAA, or better, use a custom reason.

Comment: Ok I used custom reason and was helpful and [from this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/436366/i-am-not-able-to-install-any-packages-via-apt-get-why) Can I flag other answer as NAA? deleted answer says [that](http://askubuntu.com/a/436419/283843) worked for him/her. but now I see [that answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/436419/283843) downvoted. why?